# how to download and install wxPython wheel from github for Python 3.10 to overcome disutils and setuptools problem

Tags: python, github, pip, python-wheel

Python 3.10 has a problem with disutils and setuptools>=58 in that wxPython will not run in conjunction with packages Gooey/DEAP/NEMO. I have been told there is a wxPython wheel which gets round those problems

https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2
but i cannot get the command syntax to work for  some relationship between:
"git+", #egg", "wxPython"

I tried
pip install -e git+https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl#egg=wxPython
and got

pip install -e git+https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl#egg=wxPython
Obtaining wxPython from git+https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl#egg=wxPython
Cloning https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl to c:\users\gerald\src\wxpython
Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl 'C:\Users\Gerald\src\wxpython'
fatal: https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

What is the correct pip command for this case please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new release appeared: https://pypi.org/project/wxPython/4.2.0/ . Binary wheels for w64 available for Python 3.7-3.10.

Comment: This appears to get over setuptools required to be backlevel <=58 and some disutils problems for some Python packages which require Visualstudio c++ >14.2

Answer (score 0):

Syntax `pip install git+https://URL` is used to install from sources from a Git **repository** — clone, `cd`, build wheel, install. The link `https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl` is a direct link to a wheel, it's not a Git repository (GitHub is bigger than just a hosting for reposotories, it has bug tracker, project management, hosting for release artifacts, etc.) so you shouldn't use `git+https://` syntax.

Try

```
pip install https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
```

The wheel is valid for 64-bit Python version 3.10 on Windows. Check if your Python is the one.

Comment: Nope.PS C:\Users\Gerald> pip install https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting wxPython==4.1.2a1
  Downloading https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
     - 123.1 kB 7.5 MB/s 0:00:00
ERROR: Wheel 'wxpython' located at C:\Users\Gerald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-1kgewn5x\wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is invalid.

Comment: I've said: "*Check if your Python is Python 3.10 and is 64-bit*". At least `pip --version`, please.

Comment: PS C:\Users\Gerald> pip --version                                       
pip 22.2.2 from C:\Users\Gerald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)

Comment: PyDev console: starting.
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: i just installed 3.10.6. no change.

Comment: i will retry the wheel again.

Comment: same result: PS C:\Users\Gerald> pip install https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
Collecting wxPython==4.1.2a1
  Downloading https://github.com/oleksis/youtube-dl-gui/releases/tag/v1.8.2/wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
     - 123.1 kB 7.1 MB/s 0:00:00
ERROR: Wheel 'wxpython' located at C:\Users\Gerald\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-pg_0_mnc\wxPython-4.1.2a1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl is invalid.

Comment: `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"` to check if Python is 64-bit.

Comment: BTW there is a new release: https://pypi.org/project/wxPython/4.2.0/

Comment: PS C:\Users\Gerald> python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"
64
Up to you to switch to chat. There may be a problem in where the exe is:

Comment: "C:\Users\Gerald\AppData\Local\Package Cache\{1fab56ed-b241-47a3-9abc-d51dc01b8dff}\python-3.10.6-amd64.exe"
or just older python.exe in other places.

Comment: Well, I'm out if ideas, sorry.

Comment: Since i raised this the new wxPython was released. and that works with Python 3.10.6, and a new release of DEAP. so if you give that as the answer i will accept it. Thanks for your help.